# In Typescript, why can't an internal module reference an external module?

Tags: compiler-construction, typescript

Out of curiosity, I'm wondering: Why is something like this not allowed by the compiler in Typescript? Are there security implications? Does it cause grammar issues?

```
export import Bar = require('./Path/To/Bar'); // this is allowed

module Foo {
    export import Bar = require('./Path/To/Bar'); // this is not allowed
}
```

Currently, this results in the following error:

```
Import declarations in an internal module cannot reference an external module.
```

Answer (score 1):

[All features start at -100](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx). The compiler could, in principle, distinguish external module imports from internal module imports by examining the RHS, but in practice the vast majority of external module imports are going to want to be at top-level anyway, and then we'd have to figure out what it means from a visibility perspective when a module *doesn't* export its import (for AMD it's not even clear that makes any sense).

Comment: So how could this be done?  How would we import to get type safety only?  For example, I'd like to do this:

    declare import IFoo = require("app/foo"); var foo: IFoo;

I'm looking for a way to declare foo of the same type as app/foo when app/foo exports a class without adding app/foo to the define method.

    class Foo {};
    export = Foo;